# Can we change google maps navigation voice commands using intents?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am opening google maps using intents and from what I know we can change navigation voice language manually but can we change language by passing some value using intents?

Comment: I don't think you can change Google Maps application settings via intents. Anyway, to send some additional data in intent you should use putExtra() method, but I cannot see any EXTRA_ property in the official documentation of Google Maps Android API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: is there any way to change language settings .